# Can't get R script to run from command line in windows

Tags: r, cmd

I am trying to get an R script to run via the subprocess call in python (on a windows machine). The subprocess runs and returns that is has completed but the R script has not run. So now I am just trying to get the script to execute from the command line. I get no errors, but the script won't run.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

x <- data.frame("id" = c(1, 2, 3))

write.csv(x, "x.csv")
```

This is what I have tried:

1. Add RScript to PATH `"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\bin"` and run: `Rscript.exe path\to\hello_world.R`
2. Use full path for both executable and script: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\bin\Script.exe" path\to\hello_world.R`
3. Navigate to the folder containing `hello_world.R` and execute using `RScript.exe`. I also tried using the full path to the executable.

Nothing works. I get no error, but `x.csv` does not get created.

Adding the Shebang didn't help.

Note if I run `source("hello_world.R")` from within the working directory of an R instance, things work fine and the file gets created.

I presume if the file won't execute from the cmd line, it won't execute from `subprocess()`. But I will deal with any problems there once i can get the cmd line working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. When you call `Rscript` (no args, nothing else) on the command line (after ensuring `PATH` has been updated), does it give you the "Usage" and args for the correct exe? Side point: I've had enough problems with R on windows where R was installed in `Program Files` that I stopped doing that years ago, now I install it under `C:/R/4.3.2` (or similar ... just not under prog-files); https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-install-R-for-Windows_003f discusses it a little. Perhaps reinstall under `C:\R`, reset your path, and try again?

Comment: @r2evans, for my own clarification, it mentions only on your linked page that "building of some packages from source may not work" when there are spaces in the path string, and I don't see that any package is being built here. IMO, if 'R' cannot work with Windows file and directory names without having to resort to MS-DOS 8.3 naming, then it really has no place on that OS. _It's not like `Program Files` has recently become the default location for program files, it has been there for twenty eight years!_

Comment: I agree with you, spaces in names should always work fine. 8+3 is a painful workaround in the OS that has encumbered and broken many things that should arguably never had _needed_ that kind of kruft/hack. So yes, you're mostly right, except ... several otherwise cryptic problems resolved when R, Rtools, or something else in the process/toolchain was moved from path-with-spaces to path-without-spaces. I don't know where the core issue is. For this question, I'm just suggesting one avenue to explore, not trying to open an OS flame-war; take it or leave it.

Comment: Probably the file gets created, but at a location you don't expect. Tried to specify your path `"C:/exact/path/x.csv"`?

Comment: To add to jay.sf comment: try adding `print(getwd())` to your script after the csv has been created. If the working directory is printed correctly then you should know where to look for your csv.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. @r2evans i will look at an alternative install location, but would like to try some other options first. @jay.sf & @TimTeaFan I tried setting the full filepath for the `write.csv` command, but that made no difference. Also tried adding `print(getwd())` to the script, and calling `Rscript a.R path/to/script`, but that produced nothing in the console. Likewise running that via the R instance 'source("hello_world.R")` showed the correct current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me: placing the a.R file in the parent folder of rscript.exe allowed it to run.

This produced only a 'running' output before returning to an empty prompt:

`C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Programs\R\R-4.3.2\bin\Rscript.exe  --verbose  "C:\Users\[me]\Downloads\a.R"`

Until I placed the a.R file here:

`C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Programs\R\R-4.3.2\bin\Rscript.exe "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Programs\R\a.R"`

Not sure what's going on. Placing a.R on an external/server drive also worked, but nowhere on the C drive except for the parent R folder worked for me. Hope that helps.